# Lookups in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use a sort of lookup to carry some data across from one sheet to the next. I have a form responses sheet collecting subjects a student would like to choose and from this, I have worked out how to split these choices into separate columns.

[image: Form_responses]

I then need this data taken to a second sheet where the split subjects are matched to the identical headings and a Y is put in the corresponding column for each corresponding student.

[image: corresponding_data]

Is this possible?

Comment: can you share a sample of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H1v4LT2_ENSfjtB_WtiaJGkP6z4C0t3vAN4r_-JZavc/edit?usp=sharing   I need the Y's in the columns of the subjects on the Offerings tab

Comment: @player0 Hi, there is one small anomaly I've noticed.. If a student selects 'Textiles' it doesn't produce a "Y"......? Is it something to do with the x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(C1:1, IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN({'Form Responses 1'!B2:B&"×"&
 IFERROR(SPLIT('Form Responses 1'!C2:C, ", ", ))}), "×"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1 'Email'"), 
 SEQUENCE(1, 1+COUNTUNIQUE(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 'Form Responses 1'!C2:C), ", ", )))), 0)), 
 IF(A2:A="",,ROW(A2:A)), 0)), 1, "Y"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, there is one small anomaly I've noticed.. If a student selects 'Textiles' it doesn't produce a "Y"......? Is it something to do with the x?

Comment: @MrLFenner formula in answer updated, try now

Comment: That seems to have worked! What was the issue? Thanks

Comment: @MrLFenner added +1 to COUNTUNIQUE coz it did not consider the last column (in alphabetical order Textiles was the last column of QUERY which pivots the classes)